# how do i initialise an empty Dataset/dataframe

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I need to build my results stage by stage
so I want to start with an empty Dataset/dataframe

```
Dataset<Row> output = spark.emptyDataFrame();
output = output.withColumn("Test", lit("Hello"));
output.show();
```

The above produces

```
+----+
|Test|
+----+
+----+
```

It doesn't apply the expected value as the column is created
And same thing happens when I try to extend the Dataset/dataframe with another column

```
output = output.withColumn("Test2", lit("Hello 2"));
output.show();
```

which above produces

```
+----+-----+
|Test|Test2|
+----+-----+
+----+-----+
```

Obviously the lit functions above will be replaced with my real field calculations
But I don't understand why the above is not working as expected

Appreciate any explanation/correction

Comment: Your dataset is empty, there are no rows in it.

Answer (score 0):

```
import spark.implicits._

val output = Seq(
    ("hello") 
  ).toDF("test")

+-----+
|Test |
+-----+
|hello|
+-----+
```